# Recently installed ubuntu restarted it & I get a black screen with flashing underscore but it booted when I had a windows7 dvd in the disc tray

Tags: boot

Recently installed ubuntu restarted it & I get a black screen with flashing underscore but it boots when I put a windows7 dvd in the disc tray,I installed I installed the Ubuntu OS via USB, I am just trying to figure out how I can boot independently without having any other OS installation dvd in the disc tray, My system   Memory: 2.5 GiB
                  Processor :Intel® Pentium(R) CPU E6300 @ 2.80GHz × 2
                  Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NVA8

1st time trying out any other OS other than windows

Comment: Do you get a white-on-black menu on bootup?

Comment: Nope the screens just blank with a blinking dash

Comment: *Before* that? And do you get it with the DVD in tray?

Comment: with the dvd in the tray I get the option to  press any button if I want to boot from it but I dont press anything so it boots the ubuntu OS instead, thats how I managed to boot for the very 1st time and am actually even using the ubuntu ryt now what am actually trying to do is to boot it without the windows dvd because once I try booting it without the dvd  it will not boot will get the same blank screen with the flashing uderscore

Comment: It seems your bootloader (GRUB) is corrupt. Try running `sudo update-grub` in a Terminal.

Comment: Ok now we getting somewhere, I recently figured out how to open up a terminal other than that am a newbie so av you got any tips or pointers on how I can do that, am a fast learner!

Comment: Type in `sudo update-grub` and hit Enter. It'll ask for your password like: `[sudo] password for username`. Type your normal login password. You won't see `***`s or anything - it'll appear as if nothing is being typed, but type the password in - then hit Enter. Reboot (without DVD).

Comment: Wow you did it! it worked I just rebooted & works lyk a charm thanks alot

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the bootloader (GRUB) is corrupt.

Try running `sudo update-grub`.

As to why you needed the DVD - probably because the default bootloader was corrupt and you had to use the Windows 7 DVD's bootloader (I suppose it has one?) to boot.